# How to display Text in full width of device using React Native?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I want to show the number in the complete width of the Mobile device screen.

```
    <View style={{ height: 50, alignItems: 'stretch', flex: 1 }}>
        <Text style={{ textAlign: 'justify' }}>1234 5678 9012 3456</Text>
    </View>
```

Comment: is this always going to be a single line text or will it have several lines ?

Comment: this is basically a TextInput, which has maximum length of 16 characters. @GuruparanGiritharan

Comment: If its a text you can split into multiple text components and use space-between but cant be done with a TextInput

Comment: I know how to do it with Simple text, But can you help in case of TextInput? @GuruparanGiritharan

Comment: As ive said i cant think of a way to style inside single textinput but if its something like a credit card entry there are similar questions where they use a hidden input and display the text, you can check those

Comment: thanks @GuruparanGiritharan let me check them